# Is s3cmd a safe option for sync EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, synchronization

I have the following problem: we are working on a project on AWS which will use autoscaling, so the EC2 instances will start and die very often. Freeze images, update the launch configurations, auto scalling groups, alarms, etc, takes a while and several things can go wrong.

I just want the new instances to sync the most recent code, so I was just thinking about fetching it from S3 using s3cmd once the instance finishes booting and manually updating it everytime we have new codes to be uploaded. So my doubts are:

- Is it too much risky to store the code on s3? How secure are the files in there? Using the s3cmd encryption password it is unlikely someone will be able do decrypt them?
- What other ooptions would be good for this? I was thinking about rsync, but then I think I would need to store the private key for the servers inside them, which I don't think its a good idea.

Thanks for any advices

Answer (score 0):

You might be a candidate for Elastic Beanstalk - using a plain vanilla AMI.

Then package your  application, use AWS's ebextensions tool to customize the instance when it is spun up.  ebextensions will allow you to  do anything you like to the image, in place, as it is deploying.  change .htaccess, erase a file, place a cron job, whatever.

When you have code updates, package them, upload and do a rolling update.

All instances will use your latest code, including auto-scaled ones.

The key  concept here is to never have  your real data in the instance, where it might go away if an instance dies or is shut down.

Elastic Beanstalk will allow  you to set up the load balancing, auto-scaling, monitoring, etc.

Comment: I had a quick look over this service, but I couldn't figure out if it is possible to use another linux operating system instead of the Amazon linux. I was hoping to use ubuntu server since we have more experience with it. Is this possible?